# What kind of component lets me measure distance in a small space?

Tags: sensor, distance

I have bought a [beautiful old radio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvfOh.jpg), which I'm trying to convert into a DAB radio ([there's no future for FM radio in my country](http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2015/04/20/401026037/norway-becoming-first-country-to-eliminate-fm-radio)).

Of course I could just use a DAB receiver, plug it into the old radio's speakers, and be done, but there's no fun in that. Instead, I want to be able to operate the old radio, turning its knobs and pressing its buttons. So that when I turn the tuning knob, I'm switching between DAB stations instead of tuning between FM frequencies.

The first step (at which I'm stuck) is to translate the position of the tuning knob (A) into a digital value I can use to control a DAB receiver. I'm a programmer, with only limited experience in electronics, so I'm not sure how to best accomplish this.

[[image: Overview]]

Originally, the radio displays the frequency with a vertical bar (B) that travels over a frequency band (C). My idea is to attach *something* to that bar (or to the carriage that the bar is attached to), and **measure the distance (D) between the bar (B) and the inside wall of the radio**. If I could do that with some electronic component, I could get a signal that I could translate into a number that again could be used to select a DAB station.

The problem is that space inside the radio is limited.

### Images

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdod1.jpg) shows a horisontal, round bar on which the frequency bar moves along. When the radio is fully assembled, the speakers are located on top of this, leaving about 1cm space between the horisontal bar and the speakers. It must also [go clear of two lightbulbs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bMVn.jpg) (for illuminating the frequency scale).

The frequency bar is sandwiched between the glass dial scale, and a metal plate. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZFMl.jpg) what it looks like from above.

[Here's the back of the tuning knob and its shaft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKI6g.jpg). As can be seen, there's not too much space here. The knob is dual shaft - [the outer ring is the speaker selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKlhd.jpg).

[Here is a birds-eye view of the interiors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkmES.jpg), when taken out of the enclosing cabinet. And a [close-up of the variable capacitor's shaft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgUPa.jpg), as per Transistor's request.

Oh, and [here's the schematics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpGyZ.jpg), if there are any Norwegian speaking radio enthusiasts out there.

### Here are the options I have investigated/tried so far:

- An ultrasonic rangefinder (like http://letsmakerobots.com/node/30209)
  These are too big to fit. Also, I doubt I would get any sensible signal from it, as there are many parts inside the radio that would reflect the ultrasonic waves. The same goes for [infrared rangefinders](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/242).
- A slide potentiometer (like these: http://www.potentiometers.com/select_slide.cfm)
  The ones I have found are difficult to fit, and there are not many that are longer than 10cm. The radio is ~50cm wide, so that would leave most of the band unused.
- A SoftPot (like https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8681)
  These works by reacting to mechanical pressure somewhere on the surface. They come with an "actuator", which is basically a screw with a round, plastic tip. This was promising - I attached the actuator to the part moving the bar, and let it travel along the softpot membrane. However, the tuning knob is carefully designed so that when the bar reaches one end of the scale, it stops moving, because the wire (E) that drives it will start slipping on the tuning knob to avoid damage. The pressure needed to activate the softpot was enough to cause too much friction, so that the wire was slipping, and the bar did not move.
- A string potentiometer (like these: http://www.unimeasure.com/). I could attach the string to the bar, and the stringpot housing to the inside wall. However, most stringpots I have found seem to be meant for heavy industrial use, and are priced and dimensioned accordingly. The added friction could also be an issue.

What other options do I have?

Comment: Sorry to be the bringer of bad news, but as beautiful as this question is it may be off topic for this site. Please see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Is the original radio still intact and working? If so, why not use the AM band and "listen" to the oscillator to find out where on the dial you are.

Comment: @laptop2d Well, thank you for bringing the news so gently :) I did read those links before posting, and hoped my question could be covered by "if your question generally covers … a specific electronics design problem … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!". Is the question too broad, or which off-topic reason do you mean?

Comment: Open ended questions are discouraged, and shopping questions or questions that have to do with the "consumer" electronics. Questions should not invite discussion. Questions here should be geared more toward electronic design, and not components. Questions should have specific answers. I'll I'm saying is this question may be closed.

Comment: Well, that's part of the fun you wanted! Inside the radio you'll find that the dial is changing a capacitor that is part of a tuned circuit (an oscillator basically).  You could try to figure out what frequency the tuned circuit was at and that would give you your dial position.  Something to look into?

Comment: I would think a bit harder about how to do it optically, perhaps building your own IR rangefinder - given that it's in a confined space with reflective side surfaces, you may not need optics just a transmitter and receiver with no direct line of sight.

Comment: I'm sad to hear about the FM radio in Norway. We managed to stop the craziness in Sweden, but just barely.

Comment: @laptop2d: Please leave this question open. It _is_ a design problem and while there may be no one correct answer it's the type of challenge many of us love. It gives a break from answering questions on power supplies for LED strips.

Comment: @Transistor: I added two more images. [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkmES.jpg) and a close-up [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JgUPa.jpg).

Comment: I Prefer the slide resistor that you mentioned. It has long life and more stability. it will be easy to fix with radio as well. Wishing good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider making your own linear pot using a piece of nichrome wire and a sliding contact, preferably precious metal (cannibalize it out of something).

A straight 40cm piece of AWG 30 Nichrome wire would have a resistance of about 8 or 9 ohms. If you put 100mV across it (use a voltage divider from your ADC reference and an op-amp buffer), that's only about 11mA. Then amplify the wiper voltage with a decent op-amp and you're done. Linearity should be excellent (in the 0.1% class most likely).

Comment: This sounds simple enough. Nichrome wire seems to be available quite cheap, at least from E-cigarette vendors.

Comment: I got a couple small rolls of 100' AWG30 for < $2 US ea. from China.

Comment: Remember that nichrome wire is pretty low resistance. When they make pots with it (either linear or rotary), they typically wrap a long piece around a non-conductive mandrel so that you get enough overall length to make a practical resistance (although it will still be quite low and perhaps unsuitable for a battery-powered circuit.)

Comment: @RichardCrowley That's probably why I went and calculated the actual numbers in my answer above 11mA and 100mV for 0.25mm/AWG 30. Its quite practical in fact, we've used this in production instruments. AWG 30 is also large enough to be reasonably rugged physically.

Comment: Thanks, everybody, for lots of great suggestions! I'm going to start with this one for this project, simply because it seems to be the quickest way to my goal (given my lack of knowledge), and I'd like to have a working DAB radio before they switch off the FM band in January. But for my next radio I'll go the oscillator route.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is that you forget about trying to figure out where the needle is at and build additional circuitry that interfaces with the radios tuned circuit.

You could select the AM band which tunes the internal oscillator from about 500kHz to 1.7Mhz.  If you got your hands on the schematics for this radio you could figure out where to put your "tapping" point.  The problem is not to load the circuit in a way that would alter the frequency, but that's doable.

It could even be as simple as reading the value of the variable capacitor that the dial is altering.

Doing it this way, you are less likely to deface a beautiful old radio and you'll know a bit about how radios work when it's done.

Comment: This sounds interesting, and as you've said, I was looking for fun. I'll just have to look more into how radios work, and, in particular, oscillators. I assume [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bsYxg.jpg) is oscillator related? At least these "wings" move when I work the tuning knob.

Comment: Yes, that's a large variable capacitor. Is it fixed to a PCB or can you get at its wires?

Comment: @pjc50 No PCB here. Wires are easy enough to get to.

Answer (score 4):

OK, assuming you can detach the variable capacitor from the surrounding circuitry, then it should be a simple matter to read it into a digital system. On your (rather nicely hand-drawn from before the days of CAD) schematic, it's the parts 3326/3327 at the top left just below the antenna.

If you incorporate it into a loop of Schmitt trigger buffers, you can turn the capacitance value into a frequency which can then be counted in software on a microcontroller. Adjust values of R1 until the frequency range is "sensible".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcfg5A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Nice idea. There is at least one capacitance-to-digital chip that could be used directly.

Comment: I had originally hoped I could just add my stuff somewhere, leaving the radio functioning as it was. But your suggestion sounds interesting.

Comment: This approach *might* actually work if the radio is intact, but I'm not sure. Does it really work with no further maintenance, as a tube radio? It's almost in too good condition to fiddle with at all..

Comment: Yes, the radio actually works great. Well, there are no AM or short-wave stations around anymore, so it's hard to tell. FM works, and sounds gorgeous, deep and rich.

Comment: I agree about the idea of trying not to interfere with the original radio as much as possible.  If you want a non-destructive approach, I'd start with this one (the cap wires can always be soldered back) and work towards Pete's if you're having no luck.  Good luck with it, beautiful radio and great project!

Comment: Also, the nice thing about this approach is that you could use a fixed capacitance for C1 to test your uP code.  The frequency of the above oscillator is determined by the product of R and C.  If you use a fixed R and C you can calculate the theoretical frequency and test that your uP is producing that figure, ballpark.  Then you know you're on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

The tuning knob will be driving a variable capacitor. Replace that with an ordinary potentiometer and you should be able to read its value trivially using analogue to digital conversion.

Comment: This is by far the most practical and efficient alternative. It beats my geeky, fiddly suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer:

- use a rotary encoder, axis mecanically connected to the knob axis;
- leave the frequency scale mechanism as it is.

[image]

Comment: Could be possible, but that would mean some serious disassembly of the knob, which has a lot of stuff attached to it. Also, it wouldn't give me an _absolute_ value. Since it is possible to continue turning the knob when the bar has reached the end of the band, there would be a mismatch between the bar's position and the station being listened to.

Comment: String encoder is another possibility, but probably overkill and overpriced for your application.

Comment: Or if you find a rotary encoder with low mechanical friction, just operate it from the existing belt mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

I would put a grid of [Gray Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) on the BACK of the dial scale, and a duplicate of the "cursor" on the back to read the gray code with reflective opto sensors. That would tell you the ABSOLUTE position the cursor along the dial scale. And it would be completely STATIC so that the position could be retrieved even from cold power-up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use a tiny stepper motor to a length of threaded-rod ("all-thread" as it appears to be called in Europe). Then you can use that to position the cursor at the direction of the microcontroller.

You could even use one of those "filament LED" strips to make a glowing cursor behind the glass window.